# Pandas Flat File Output

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, flat

I'm reading in a .csv file with pandas, and after doing some minor mods to some headers and a few concatenations I need to turn the file into a flat file such that each row is separated as such:

Row 1(Not Needed in output)

column,value

column,value

column,value

Row 2(Not Needed in output)

column,value

column,value

column,value

IE

Name,Fred

Phone,555-555-5555

Office,Jackson

Name,Mary

Phone,555-555-5555

Office,Gulf Port

Name,Willie

Phone,555-555-5555

Office,Jackson

etc....

and save it to file in that format.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

You can try something like this:

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_csv('x.csv')
```

Comment: @InBox I am glad that worked for you.  You're welcome.  Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer.